# conditionally paste information from one var to another

Tags: r

I'm trying to conditionally paste information from one variable into another, so that I go from having a data frame like dfsummary to one like dfgoal.

In my attempt I've tried to use  ^ and $ to make the grepl() match exact but it's not working. Also, my attempt only deals with dfsummary$SumVarName[1], whereas I'd like it to work its way through all of dfsummary$SumVarName.

Thanks for any help!

```
# Starting point 
dfsummary <- data.frame(SumVarName=c("CarMake, SK4+","CarMake, SK4","Customer, highend - in","Customer, highend - out","price, expensive"),SumVarNumber=c("12 (43%)","16 (57%)","9 (39%)","11 (61%)","8 (40%)"))
dfmain <- data.frame(MainName=c("CarMake, SK4+ vs ref","Customer, highend - in vs ref"))


# Goal
dfgoal<- data.frame(MainName=c("CarMake, SK4+ vs ref","Customer, highend - in vs ref"),MainVarNumber=c("12 (43%)","9 (39%)"))


# Attempt 
dfmain$MainVarNumber <- NA
dfmain$MainVarNumber[1][grepl(^dfsummary$SumVarName[1]$,dfmain$MainName[1])] <- paste0(dfsummary$SumVarNumber[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straight forward idea is to split the column by `vs`, merge and then `unite` again the two columns, i.e. (in `tidyverse`)

```
library(tidyverse)

dfmain %>% 
 separate(MainName, into = c('SumVarName', 'v2'), sep = ' vs ') %>% 
 left_join(dfsummary) %>% 
 unite(MainName, SumVarName, v2, sep = ' vs ')
```

which gives,

> ```
> #Joining, by = "SumVarName"
>                     MainName SumVarNumber
> 1          CarMake vs SK4+_ref     12 (43%)
> 2 Customer vs highend - in_ref      9 (39%)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A similar idea to that of Sotos...

```
library(dplyr)
merge(dfmain,
      mutate(dfsummary,
             SumVarName = paste0(dfsummary$SumVarName, ' vs ref')),
      by.y = 'SumVarName', by.x = 'MainName')
```